# convert c programming file with mex functions

Tags: python, c, matlab

I have a c file which contains mex functions(for matlab).

how can I use those mex function file using python without matlab?

1. I can convert c file into dll ?
2. mex to c?
3. Any other way?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check google or e.g. the visual studio express documentation (assuming that you're on windows). mex-files actually are dll's, they only differ in the naming to make matlab recognize them.
2. Nope.
3. See below.

If the functions you actually want to use work with the `mxArray` types - then you can't. Simply because without using matlab you cannot create `mxArray` objects. So you'd e.g. have to use the matlab C-interface to open a matlab-engine etc.

If you'd like to use other "helper" functions that work with standard c-types (`double`, `int`, etc..) from the c-file, then yes.
Check the python docs:

- http://docs.python.org/2/extending/
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Or, alternatively, there are tools able to create c-to-python wrappers, like http://www.swig.org and others.